# Unix Timestamp gives me a date that is about 40,000 years in the future

Tags: java, date, unix, datetime

so I get a String that is a date. Example: `2012-10-22 10:00:00` Now I want the Unix Timestamp of this date. So first I have to convert it into a `SimpleDateFormat`

```
String metaDate             = (metaDateList.item(0)).getNodeValue(); //2012-10-22 10:00:00 
SimpleDateFormat sdf        = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date nonUnixDate;
nonUnixDate                 = sdf.parse(metaDate);
System.out.println ( nonUnixDate.getTime() );`
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the unix timestamp is `1358675994000` which is `Thu, 23 Sep 45024 14:20:00 GMT`. Seems like I have an error somewhere, but where is it?

Comment: One immediate error is that you use "mm" twice - use "MM" for month!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is defined in seconds.

[`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) returns milliseconds.

So your result will be off by a factor of 1000.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong format, you should use MM

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf        = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```